# Admin Controllers in Merb

Tags: ruby, merb

How does one do namespaced controllers in Merb, for instance to create an admin section to the site? In Rails one would use Admin::CategoriesController, is this similar in Merb or is this another recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace method seems to do it.

This is placed in the routes file (router.rb):

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :categories
end
```

This generates routes like:

```
edit_admin_category - /admin/categories/:id/edit(.:format)
delete_admin_category - /admin/categories/:id/delete(.:format)
admin_categories - /admin/categories(/index)(.:format)
new_admin_category - /admin/categories/new(.:format)
admin_category - /admin/categories/:id(.:format)
```

I then put my controller in a module like this:

```
module Admin
  class Categories < Application
    def index
      ...
    end

    .
    .
    .
  end
end
```

I am not sure if this is the recommended way, any suggestions to this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, but for what it's worth, I had a hard time trying to make use of the new route with link_to in my views.

I ended up getting this to work:

```
<%= link_to("Categories Admin", resource(:admin, :categories) %>
```